# module not available in release

Tags: elixir, distillery

I have a small Elixir application that uses [feeder_ex](https://github.com/manukall/feeder_ex) to parse XML. In development everything works well but when I build my release with [distillery](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery) I start getting an `unavailable xmerl module` error.

I solved it by adding the `xmerl` application to the application list under my mix.exs. But it doesn't make sense to me because I already have `feeder_ex` to my application list. And `feeder_ex` have `feeder` to his application list which have `xmerl` to his application list.

So why do I have to declare it one more time in my own application list?

### Update - add Erlang version / command result

**xmerl =>**

```
iex(3)> i :xmerl 
Term
  :xmerl
Data type
  Atom
Module bytecode
  /home/awea/.asdf/installs/erlang/19.3/lib/erlang/lib/xmerl-1.3.13    /ebin/xmerl.beam
```

**erl =>**

```
erl                                                                                                                                    
Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10]       [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
```

### Update - add Linux version, vm.args

I using ubuntu 16.04 and distillery 1.5.2. Here is my `vm.args` file:

```
#### Generated - edit/create /var/apps/vigil/vm.args instead.
## Name of the node
-name vigil@127.0.0.1

## Cookie for distributed erlang
-setcookie -

## Heartbeat management; auto-restarts VM if it dies or becomes unresponsive
## (Disabled by default..use with caution!)
##-heart

## Enable kernel poll and a few async threads
##+K true
##+A 5

## Increase number of concurrent ports/sockets
##-env ERL_MAX_PORTS 4096

## Tweak GC to run more often
##-env ERL_FULLSWEEP_AFTER 10

# Enable SMP automatically based on availability
-smp auto
```

### Update - add application list

```
def application do
  [mod: {Vigil, []},
    extra_applications: [
      :logger, :xmerl
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should probably better post this to `mix` issue tracker.

Comment: @mudasobwa The strangest thing is that `xmerl` is an erlang module, shouldn't be included by default ? I use `zip` in another application without this problem ^^ I'll try poping an issue on distillery repo first.

Comment: Hmmm. Good question. What prints `i :xmerl` in your `iex`? What version of Erlang do you use?

Comment: @mudasobwa I've updated my question

Comment: Would you try `iex -S mix run` _without_ `:xmerl` explicitly included in the applications list and `i :xmerl` in the prompt line?

Comment: @mudasobwa I get the same result as before.

Comment: It would also help if you specified your OS (Mac or Linux and if so which flavor of Linux) and your version of distillery.  Also post up your vm.args (the expanded one not the eex)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I updated my question

Comment: @Awea how did you add `xmerl` to your application list? I am having this exact issue and I tried your solution but I think maybe I am doing something wrong as it is still happening.

```applications: [
        :phoenix,
        :phoenix_pubsub,
        *a few more*,
        :xmerl
      ],
```

Could you possibly put a copy of your application list up or point out what is wrong with mine. Thanks

Comment: @RobStallion I've added my application list :)

Comment: @Awea Thanks so much for replying and updating your question. I have added `:xmerl` to into my extra applications as you have shown above, unfortunately I am still getting the same error. Did you have to add it into your list of `deps` also? And if so how did you do that? If you could think of any steps I my have missed please feel free to point them out. Thanks again